# Custom Transformer in sklearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, transformer-model

I am building a transformer in sklearn which drops features that have a correlation coefficient lower than a specified threshold.

It works on the training set. However, when I transform the test set. All features on the test set disappear. I assume the transformer is calculating correlations between test data and training label and since those are all low, it is dropping all features. How do I make it only calculate correlations on the training set and drop those features from the test set on the transform?

```
class CorrelatedFeatures(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin): #Selects only features that have a correlation coefficient higher than threshold with the response label
    def __init__(self, response, threshold=0.1):
        self.threshold = threshold
        self.response = response
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self
    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        df = pd.concat([X, self.response], axis=1)
        cols = df.columns[abs(df.corr()[df.columns[-1]]) > self.threshold].drop(self.response.columns)
        return X[cols]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You calculate and store that correlation and the columns to be dropped in `fit()`, and in `transform()` just transform those columns.

Something like this:

```
....
....

def fit(self, X, y=None):
    df = pd.concat([X, self.response], axis=1)
    self.cols = df.columns[abs(df.corr()[df.columns[-1]]) > self.threshold].drop(self.response.columns)
    return self
def transform(self, X, y=None):
    return X[self.cols]
```